# How to create data connection and submitting between InfoPath 2010 and SQL Server 2008 (Live Server)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-connection, form-submit, infopath2010

I was create an Infopath 2010 form from Databse Form Template. The database source that I used on a live server (need internet connection). I've done to create the form. But when I try to submit the entries from the form, I get error that says:

> InfoPath cannot submit the form. 
>   An error occurred while the form was being submitted.
>   InfoPath cannot connect to the data source. 
>   Access is denied. 
>   Access is denied.

I create this form based from this [tutorial](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2010/connect-infopath-2010-sql-server-2008-table.htm)

Can I submit the infopath form to SQL Server on live server directly? Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have a write permission to that database table?

Comment: I followed the tutorial and was able to submit form data to my sql. Are you using windows authentication to access SQL Server?

Comment: yes, I use windows auth to access my SQL Server. Is that wrong?

Comment: No its not wrong at all. Does your SQL Server reside on the same machine that has InfoPath? Just want to make sure if SQL server is in diff server. If that's the case, then can you check if as an admin in the server that hosts SQL, can yo usubmit your form?

Comment: @Nemo SQL Server is in the different server. okay, I'll check that and give you update :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the form settings to allow data to be sumbitted to a form:
1. Click on tool >>form options>> Security and trust
2. Select the full trust option

(Answer was taking from other site, but I post it here because when I was looking for the answer I had seen this site the very first)